# Checking custom gradient easily with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a surprisingly simple question: I have implemented a complex custom op and its gradient in Tensorflow, assuming the forward is correct, I was wondering if there was an easy way to check if the finite differences approximates well your custom gradient at different points without having to re-implement it in an ugly way. I saw the function `tf.test.compute_gradient_error()`[in the official doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/compute_gradient_error) but the source code is dense and hard to read and I cannot seem to find any other related questions or examples.
However I am sure there is one super simple self-contained example lying around that I missed ?
**EDIT:**
For instance if I try:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
start=np.random.normal(size=(100,1)).astype("float32")
x=tf.Variable(start)
w=2*tf.ones((1,1),dtype="float32")
y=tf.matmul(x,w)
#I differentiate y wrt x, which is a variable
check=tf.test.compute_gradient_error(x,[100,1],y,[100,1],x_init_value=start)
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
sess.run(check)
```

It throws: 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run'
Looking into gradient_checker.py what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the problem with the function you mentioned? It does exactly what you want it to. It calculates the numerical error of the gradient.

Comment: @ThomasPinetz I guess I am looking for indications on how to use it.

Comment: With correct parameters

Comment: Like how would you go about testing it (and interpret the results (is this error big or not ?)) for tensorflow analytical gradient for tf.square or something like that to get a somewhat non equivocal result like this gradient seems to be good .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my problem was that `gradient_checker.py` calls `get_default_session()` to get the session it uses, which apparently does not work if the op is not explicitly connected to the session in use, which is done by scoping the op:

```
with sess.as_default_session():
  check=tf.test.compute_gradient_error()
  print check
```

It also needs to be said that the reason it needs to be this way comes from the fact that check is directly the result to a `sess.run()` of a tensor and not a node in the graph like most tensorflow functions.